# Spark not locating client program via spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkcore

I am trying to deploy the spark job into spark cluster and facing an issue with classloading I believe.

Error details as below:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.examples.datasets.FlightDataProcessor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:810)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/06/02 06:26:11 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Currently, I have to copy the application jars to spark `jars` folder as part of the deployment script to solve this issue.

But I believe that `spark-submit` driver should have intelligently done this thing as everytime I want deploy some spark job I need to copy all client programs to `jars` its not convenient at all

**Environment Info:**

Spark version: `2.11-2.4.3`

Scala version: `2.11.8`

Here is a link to my source code:

**Deployment Script**

https://github.com/anhtv08/spark-cassandra-example/blob/master/scripts/submit_spark_flight_job.sh

**Spark job code**

https://github.com/anhtv08/spark-cassandra-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/examples/datasets/FlightDataProcessor.scala

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is available is part of a jar, we can upload the jar to hdfs or a maven repo and use either of following options.
*  [--jars/spark.jars](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) - we can specify the path to the jars uploaded to HDFS.
*  [--packages/spark.jars.packages](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) - we can specify the maven co-ordinates if we are able to upload the jar to a maven repo(Also we need to specify the credentials to the Spark about the maven repo)

Comment: I am running in the local mode and have tried to specified the `file:///` schema, but did not get succeeded. any hint on submitting local in the local mode

All my setup is in the local machine and I am able to run though IntelliJ

I am looking the official doc:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html